# The number of possible $4$ digit numbers with ordered digits

Tags: combinatorics

So I was taking a math test and I was stuck on a question asking,

> How many possible $4$ digit numbers are there where each digit is lower than the one before it?

I wasn't sure how to account for each of the outcomes for each digit.

Comment: At what level do you expect yhe answer? For example, can we assume that you know how to calculate the number of ways to pick $n$ objects out of $m\ge n$ without regard to the order they are picked? Now, what happens if you just pick 4 digits out of {0,1,...,9} and then order them in a decreasing sequence - won't that give you the 4-digit numbers you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick 4 digits out of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ (there are ${10\choose 4}=210$ ways to do that). Order each choice in decreasing sequence and this gives you a unique 4-digit number of a desired form. Thus there are 210 such numbers.

Comment: Ok, that is the answer that was given in the answer key, also how would you do this if the number 5223 would be allowed, if the problem was How many possible 4 digit numbers are there where each digit is lower than or equal to the one before it?

Comment: For better visibility, I suggest you post this as a separate question on MSE. BTW 5223 does not satisfy the condition you’ve just mentioned, so I am not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant 5332, and I have posted a new question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540523/the-number-of-possible-four-digit-numbers-with-ordered-digits

Answer (score 0):

A number fitting that description with a starting digit of $n$, and the digits in sequential order, would fit this summation:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{n+4}10^{n-k+3}k$$

As for numbers such as 1235, I don't really know

Comment: Please see the answer posted by user8734617.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I guess I thought of this from a different, less useful angle

Comment: Though this doesn't really work for this particular question it can still have many interesting use cases and was definitely worth a look.